# Could not set css z-index on images using bootstrap rails project

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have been working on a rails project, there are some images and css icon which comes over Header when I scroll down the landing page. I have searched for z-index and set to 1000+ but still it comes above the header.

Here is the project Url: http://mentoring-campus.herokuapp.com/

What wrong with the css code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row that contain those pictures have a .animated class. That class has a "z-index: 100;" which makes those pictures show above your header.

Comment: Thank you @JX0, been able to fix by adding inline css.

Comment: @Eltaf no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the z-index of the divs that are showing up on top of the header to -1 it will fix it. Looks like those divs are the ones with the 'wow' class.

Answer (score 0):

This is often considered bad practice, but you could use:

```
z-index: 999 !important;
```

or even use inline

```
style="z-index: 999"
```

To do this properly, you should make sure your own css is included after the css that gives these pictures a z-index